# Dynamically creating rows & columns in Angular + Bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to dynamically create rows in angular template and every row is fixed to 4-columns. For eg. if my input is 40, result must have 10 rows and each row consists of 4 columns. I am using bootstrap for template. This is how far i have got but not working.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let r of row">
  <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let i of id">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

The .ts code:

```
id: number = 40;
row: number = id / 4;
```

How to achieve the result. The problem is same as matrix but in template how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
  id: number = 40;
  row: number = Math.ceil(this.id / 4);
  row1 = Array(this.row).fill(1);
  id1 = Array(4).fill(0).map((_, index) => index + 1);
  row2 = Array(this.id).fill(1).map((_, index) => index + 1);

constructor() {
    var chunk_size = 4;
    var arr = this.row2;
    var groups = arr.map(function (e, i) {
      return i % chunk_size === 0 ? arr.slice(i, i + chunk_size) : null;
    })
      .filter(function (e) { return e; });
    this.matrix = groups;
  }

<div class="row" *ngFor="let r of row1;let i =index">
  <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let i of matrix[i]">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-row

Comment: this is different than what i asked. It's printing 1,1,1,1.... but i want 1,2,3,4.... Can you please modify it? Also if the input changes to lets say 3.. it doesn't print anything.

Comment: check the stackblitz now

Comment: I think i wasn't clear enough, the result should be like.. row1-> 1,2,3,4, row2-> 5,6,7,8... this way

Comment: It's working now but when the input is not completely divisible by 4, it displays nothing. Eg. change the id value(40) to something like 39 in stackblitz. it should print the numbers till 39 in 10th row and 3rd col..

Comment: @Chellappan, could you please have a look at the comment above, i observed that no data is displayed when the input (id) is not divisible by 4

Comment: @zeddysoft Hi you can use Math.round or some other build js method to  make the value nearest integer